# Cannot subscript a value of type [Dictionary<String, Any>] with an index of type 'String'

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, swift3, alamofire

I'm trying to read some data that is returned to me from Alamofire but I'm getting this error while trying to navigate the JSON. Here is my code:

```
Alamofire.request(requestURL).responseJSON { response in
  if let JSON = response.result.value as? [Dictionary<String, Any>] {

      if let reviews = JSON["reviews"] as? [Dictionary<String, Any>] { //Its giving me the error here
          for review in reviews {
              print(review["description"])
          }
      }

  }
}
```

And the error I'm getting:

> Cannot subscript a value of type [Dictionary] with an index of type 'String'

This is the JSON i'm working with:

```
{
  "item": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring",
    "description": "A meek Hobbit from the Shire and eight companions set out on a journey to destroy the powerful One Ring and save Middle Earth from the Dark Lord Sauron."
  },
  "cast": {
    "roles": [
      {
        "actor": {
          "name": "Sean Astin"
        },
        "character": {
          "name": "Sam"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "fullDescription": "An ancient Ring thought lost for centuries has been found, and through a strange twist in fate has been given to a small Hobbit named Frodo. When Gandalf discovers the Ring is in fact the One Ring of the Dark Lord Sauron, Frodo must make an epic quest to the Cracks of Doom in order to destroy it! However he does not go alone. He is joined by Gandalf, Legolas the elf, Gimli the Dwarf, Aragorn, Boromir and his three Hobbit friends Merry, Pippin and Samwise. Through mountains, snow, darkness, forests, rivers and plains, facing evil and danger at every corner the Fellowship of the Ring must go. Their quest to destroy the One Ring is the only hope for the end of the Dark Lords reign!",
  "reviews": [
    {
      "description": "something",
      "star": {
        "value": 5
      },
      "userName": "some name"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas?? I'm new to Swift, thank you very much!

Comment: Didn't read thoroughly, but the square brackets suggest it has an array of dictionaries which must be subscripted via the index number.  Where as, based on the error, you are probably trying to access it as just a dictionary using the string key.

Comment: `if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cause of the error is that the line:

```
if let JSON = response.result.value as? [Dictionary<String, Any>] {
```

is telling the compiler that `JSON` is an array. But then in the line:

```
if let reviews = JSON["reviews"] as? [Dictionary<String, Any>] {
```

you attempt to access an element of that array using a `String` index. Hence the error from the compiler.

But your top level JSON is a dictionary, not an array. So change this line:

```
if let JSON = response.result.value as? [Dictionary<String, Any>] {
```

to:

```
if let JSON = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
```

or to:

```
if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String : Any] {
```

This will fix your error and actually match your data.